# Division using variables in assembly language 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly language. I was practising division in assembly language and I had a doubt about dividing using variables

```
num1 db 10

mov ax , num1 <br>
mov bl , 2  <br>
div bl
```

But this creates an `error (39) wrong parameters: MOV  ax , num1
(39) operands do not match: 16 bit register and 8 bit address`

Can anyone help me understand this ?

Comment: It's exactly what it says. Your `num1` is a `db`, a single byte. `ax` is 16 bits, 2 bytes. You want `movzx ax, num1` to zero extend to the larger size.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
movzx is not valid in emu8086
But I've used 
mov ah , 00
mov al , num1
This worked!

Comment: Similar problem with emu8086 missing `movzx`  is solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442174/palindrome-program-for-emu8086-in-assembly-language/61444797#61444797